# What's the minimum pixel that can be used in CSS?

Tags: css

Just out of curiosity.
What's the minimum pixel that can be used in CSS?
For example: `margin-top: 1.2345px`. Is it effective?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Seems like you would round up or down 1.4 or 1.6.

Comment: @Roj I'm not trying anything. Just out of curiosity :P

Comment: @NormanLin ah okay. well there's no constraint. you can go as many with decimal places.

Answer (score 4):

There is no constraint on the number of decimal places for the `px` unit value. According to [the CSS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/syndata.html#length-units):

> The format of a length value (denoted by  in this specification) is a  (with or without a decimal point) immediately followed by a unit identifier (e.g., px, em, etc.). After a zero length, the unit identifier is optional.

If your question is "what's the smallest visible increment that browsers will render", it depends on the browser and your perception abilities. Here's an article from a few years back exploring fractional-pixel rendering:

- https://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/browsers-and-fractional-pixels/

**In summary, "supply any decimal value you want, but you might not see a difference between `1.2px` and `1.2345px`."**